# chrome desktop HTML notification

Tags: ajax, google-chrome

I have implement chrome extension from:

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications.html

How to add html notification that can read from my server mysql and if there is new info than it will fire new notification?

Comment: I just downloaded sample notification and add it to my browser.I would like to change to html notification: var notification = webkitNotifications.createHTMLNotification(
  'notification.html'  // html url - can be relative
);  Hoew can i configure notification.html to get data frommy server url?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't very clear what you are trying to achieve. Have a look at this plugin: http://athousandnodes.com/article/html5-desktop-notification. Works in Chrome, Safari, and Opera according to dev.

Comment: thanks for reply, but I would like to do it within extension. Like that my website don't need to be open to show notification.